# How to record accelerometer data from Nike+?

Tags: iphone, nike

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not.
I'd like to receive accelerometer data from Nike+.

Actually, some data related with running history is recorded in XML format on the iPhone.
But the XML file doesn't include accelerometer data.

Is is possible for iPhone to receive accelerometer data from Nike+, then to write the x-y-z signals to some file, like an XML file on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Nike+ may use an iPhone but it doesn't record the data using the accelerometer, it either uses data transmitted from the pedometer or by using the in built GPS.

Having retrieved data from the Nike+ website, they have only recently started collecting/exposing more data and accelerometer information isn't one of them.

It is possible that the 7th generation Nano (maybe previous ones too) returns some sort of accelerometer data,  as they don't rely on any sensors to collect running data but act as a pedometer themselves. I doubt it, but there's a very small possibility.